# Allow access to user in Spring Security if he has both roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security for providing access to users of my application. For single role I am using like this:

```xml
<security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/Admin" access="hasAuthority('Admin')" />
```

I want to provide access to user for a particular URL if he has both role of `Admin` and `Employee` but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-access-web):

> To use expressions to secure individual URLs, you would first need to
>   set the `use-expressions` attribute in the `<http>` element to `true`.
>   Spring Security will then expect the `access` attributes of the
>   `<intercept-url>` elements to contain Spring EL expressions. The
>   expressions should evaluate to a Boolean, defining whether access
>   should be allowed or not. For example:
>
> ```xml
> <http>
>     <intercept-url pattern="/admin*"
>         access="hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')"/>
>     ...
> </http>
> ```

So, you should try using:

```xml
<security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/Admin" 
    access="hasAuthority('Admin') and hasAuthority('Employee')" />
```